# Syntax error when trying to await "(awaitable) Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation"

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asynchronous, windows-phone-8

I'm getting a really confusing error Message from Visual Studio, telling me I cannot use "await" on a method that is marked "(awaitable)." Here is the full message:

> Error 1   The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method. Consider marking this method with the 'async' modifier and changing its return type to `'Task<Windows.Phone.Media.Capture.AudioVideoCaptureDevice>'`

And here is my code:

```
    private AudioVideoCaptureDevice SetupController()
    {
        CameraSensorLocation Location = CameraSensorLocation.Back;
        AudioVideoCaptureDevice CameraController = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(Location, AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(Location).First());

        CameraController.SetProperty(KnownCameraAudioVideoProperties.VideoTorchMode, VideoTorchMode.On);

        return CameraController;
    }
```

The error is with this line:

```
AudioVideoCaptureDevice CameraController = await AudioVideoCaptureDevice.OpenAsync(Location, AudioVideoCaptureDevice.GetAvailableCaptureResolutions(Location).First());
```

Comment: It's not telling you that you cannot use `await` *on* a non-`async` method; it's telling you that you cannot use `await` *in* a non-`async` method. It's complaining about `SetupController`, not `OpenAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using await - you must use it within a method that supports asynchronous operation. And as you are returning a value - make it a `Task<>`

Try to make your method async:

```
private async Task<AudioVideoCaptureDevice> SetupController()
{
  // your code
}
```

And as it's now asynchronous then use it:

```
AudioVideoCaptureDevice myDevice = await SetupController(); // which should also be run from async method
```

Comment: Also, [the method should end in `Async`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx).